# View for a MANY_MANY_MANY relationship

Tags: mysql, view, foreign-key, relational-theory

Let's say I have 3 main tables:
`category`, `tag`, `url`

`category` and `tag` have a MANY_MANY relationship (`category_tag`).

`tag` and `url` have a MANY_MANY relationship (`url_tag`).

I would like for a given category to retrieve all the linked urls.

What is the easiest, most efficient way to do this?

Could I maybe build a "VIEW"? What would be the query?

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulating the queries into Views or not, is your choice. For every one of the below queries, you can create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW category_url AS
  ( Query
  ) ;
```

If you want only the IDs of the categories and URLs, the simplest (joining only 2 tables) is this - no need for joining the `tag` table, as long as the foreign key constraints are defined:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ct.category_id,
        ut.url_id 
    FROM  
        category_tag AS ct 
      JOIN 
        url_tag AS ut
          ON ut.tag_id = ct.tag_id
```

or (the equivalent) which can be easily extended to include the number of tags relating a category with a url:

```
    SELECT 
        ct.category_id,
        ut.url_id,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_joining_tags         --- optional
    FROM  
        category_tag AS ct 
      JOIN 
        url_tag AS ut
          ON ut.tag_id = ct.tag_id 
    GROUP BY 
        ct.category_id,
        ut.url_id
```

---

If you also want columns from the `category` and `url` tables as well (which is very probable), you need to join those tables, too:

```
    SELECT 
        ct.category_id,
        ut.url_id,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_joining_tags,        --- optional

        c.*,                                       --- the columns from `category`
        u.*                                        --- and `url` that you need
    FROM  
        category_tag AS ct 
      JOIN 
        url_tag AS ut
          ON ut.tag_id = ct.tag_id 

      JOIN 
        category AS c 
          ON c.id = ct.category_id
      JOIN 
        url AS u
          ON u.id = ut.url_id

    GROUP BY 
        ct.category_id,
        ut.url_id
```

Answer (score -1):

I created the following VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW category_url AS
(SELECT DISTINCT category.id AS category_id, url.id AS url_id 
FROM category
JOIN category_tag ON category_tag.category_id=category.id
JOIN url_tag ON url_tag.tag_id = category_tag.tag_id
JOIN url ON url.id = url_tag.url_id)
```

Comment: I don't know why I picked LEFT JOIN. Would INNER JOIN be more appropriate?

Comment: yes left joins are inappropriate as they will give superflous rows.  You only want to use them where for example you want to list a category that has no urls and then you should only need 1 left join among the rest as inner joins.

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this a good solution now?